Using sympy to integrate function - doesn't return algebraic/numerical output
This is my first time on overflow and I'm pretty new to using Jupyter and sympy. I'm trying to integrate a function numerically as it simply cannot be done analytically, and here's the code:

from sympy import exp, integrate, symbols
b, G, a, P = symbols('b G a P', nonzero=True, positive=True, real=True, constant=True)
t=symbols('t', positive=True, real=True)

f = 1/((1-b*G*t))**2*exp(-a*G/(1-b*G*t)-t/P)
res = integrate(f, (t, 0, 1/(b*G)))
print (res)



I'm not encountering any errors on running it, but the result is simply
Integral(exp(-t/P)*exp(-G*a/(-G*b*t + 1))/(G*b*t - 1)**2, (t, 0, 1/(G*b)))
which is just the integral itself unsolved.
I don't even know how to begin troubleshooting, any idea why this is happening?

what do you expect the end of the integration to be ? 1/(G*B) is not a number.

unevaluated integral, numerical integration. Have a look at all the sections anyway:)

to do numerical integration the only variable in the equation should be t, other symbols should be substituted by numbers before the integration, then you apply any of the answers mentioned above.

i got things swapped around in the original post - i need to be able to solve this analytically and keep the variables as they are
